# How to retrieve uid according to that PhoneNumber while registration in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uid

I have registerButton and otpButton for successful registration to the app.
in registerButton tapping i am sending otp to that registered phonenumber. after otp verification in otpButton then the person successfully registered and i will get `uid` .

now i want to check if user is already registered or not while registration.. for that i have saved uid in otpButton.. and retrieving uid in registerButton to check if uid is not nil then to show alert message... but here all the time including new user also i am getting recently registered person uid WHY?

How to check if user is already registered or not with their phone number.

saving uid in otpButton:

```
do{
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
print("the json of otppppppppp \(json)")
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if (self.otpTextField.text == String(self.otpField ?? 12)){
        print("registration successfullllll...")
        let mobileNum = json["mobile_number"] as! [String : Any]
        self.regUid = mobileNum["id"] as? String
        print("otp uid \(String(describing: self.regUid))")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.regUid!, forKey: "regUid")
        }
        print("the otp uid keywrap \(KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.regUid!, forKey: "regUid"))")

        let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
        self.present(loginVC, animated: true)
    }
}
}
```

retrieving uid to check if user is already registered or not

```
do{
let userId: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "regUid")
print("reg userid \(userId)")
if userId != nil{
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "Title", message: "user exist", in: self)
    }
}
else{
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
    print("the json regggggggggggis \(json)")
    let phNum = json["mobile_number"] as? Int
    let status = json["status"] as? String
    self.otpField = json["otp"] as? Int
}
}
```

Please help me to check if user exist or not while registration according to uid.

Answer (score 0):

**used mobile number instead of regUid as a key chain key**

```
do{
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
print("the json of otppppppppp \(json)")
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if (self.otpTextField.text == String(self.otpField ?? 12)){
        print("registration successfullllll...")
        let mobileNum = json["mobile_number"] as! [String : Any]
        self.regUid = mobileNum["id"] as? String
        print("otp uid \(String(describing: self.regUid))")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.regUid!, forKey: mobileNum)
        }
        print("the otp uid keywrap \(KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.regUid!, forKey: mobileNum))")

        let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
        self.present(loginVC, animated: true)
    }
}
}

let mobileNumber = ""  // set mobile number
do{
let userId: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: mobileNumber)
print("reg userid \(userId)")
if userId != nil{
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "Title", message: "user exist", in: self)
    }
}
else{
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
    print("the json regggggggggggis \(json)")
    let phNum = json["mobile_number"] as? Int
    let status = json["status"] as? String
    self.otpField = json["otp"] as? Int
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, how can i check if user exist or not

Comment: let mobileNumber = ""  // set mobile number... what should i set here... i want to check if uid exist then user exist condition... please help me here, i got stuck here from long time

Comment: @iosSwift use mobileNum as key. if user already login with same mobile number then you get the userId otherwise it is nil.

Comment: no, i dont want if user is login or not,.... i want if user is is already registered with phnum or he is a new user means first time using that phnum for registeration

Comment: mobileNum is a distionary.  `self.regUid = mobileNum["id"] as? String` here i am getting id

Comment: use mobile Number in which you get the OTP instead of  let mobileNum = json["mobile_number"] as! [String : Any].